# tar: Error opening archive: Can't initialize filter; unable to run program "bzip2 -d"

Tags: bzip2

I'm trying to run this code from : https://github.com/pnnl/safekit ,using cmd on windows 10, I already installed python. 
when I type the command:

```
tar -xjvf data_examples.tar.bz2
```

I keep getting the error:

> tar: Error opening archive: Can't initialize filter; unable to run
>   program "bzip2 -d"

I have tried to download bzip2 through easy-7 zip and GnuWin32 , but it didn't work.
Can any one help me?

P.S.: I did search for the same problem before posting mine.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem! My non-elegant solution so far has been to force Windows's `tar.exe` to use the `bzip2.exe` provided with my Windows [Git](https://git-scm.com/) installation. The trick is to add to your user `PATH` the directory where `bzip2.exe` is located, in my case:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
```

So, right now my PATH looks like:

```
Path=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
```

Notice that I've only touched the user environment PATH, not the system PATH, and I've **appended** the new directory. As always, touching your PATH can be a little bit dangerous, proceed with care. If someone has a better solution, I'd be glad to hear it.

**Note:** I tried copying the `bzip2.exe` to a separate directory, but this didn't work (I presume because `bzip2.exe` couldn't find some dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command in git bash instead of cmd it should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30306570)

Answer (score 0):

I just extracted the file with 7zip

Per context menu.

Very unstylish yes. but it worked.